# How to set up tor private network without the simulator

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, private, shadow

Is there a way to make the private tor network do not use the simulator, such as shadow or chutney? If possible, do you how can I set up?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using multile Tor instances and virtual network+VLanS. Tor does not needs *any* "emulator" software: all the roles are implemented and running on `tor` binary

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, chutney is not actually a simulator, it starts up a bunch of Tor nodes on a single machine and configures them to talk to each other. If you want to set up a private Tor network that's split up across machines, I think you'll have to do it manually, though experimenting with a chutney configuration would be a good starting point.